# Converting DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
np.random.seed(10)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
              'y':[10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20],
              'z':np.random.normal(size = 10)
              })
```

I want to convert the `x` values into columns and `y` values into index (**decreasing**) with corresponding z values in the dataframe. It's something like this df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,5), index = [20,10], columns=[1,2,3,4,5])
```

How can I conver `df1` into `df2`'s style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.pivot_table`:

```
res = df1.pivot_table(index='y', columns='x', values='z')
```

You may wish to remove or change your index names, but this is your result:

```
x          1         2         3         4         5
y                                                   
10  1.331587  0.715279 -1.545400 -0.008384  0.621336
20 -0.720086  0.265512  0.108549  0.004291 -0.174600
```

Comment: Can I have the index to be decreased `y`? From 20 at first row to 10 at second row in this case.

Comment: @YQ.Wang, I'm sure that's possible. You can look up how to sort indices in pandas. Something like `.sort_index(ascending=False)` might work.